# How can I solve this in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to extract which option has been selected from the code below in Apps Script. The idea is to change the value of the global variable column depending on which element is selected, but it is not working.

html

```
<select class="form-select" id="seleccion">
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

java

```
var column;
function optionSelec(){
var e = document.getElementById("seleccion");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

if (strUser == 1){column = [1]};
if (strUser == 2){column = [2]};
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: About `How can I solve this in Google Apps Script?`, can you provide your current script including your Google Apps Script? Because I thought that it is required to know the method for communicating between Javascript side and Google Apps Script side in your situation.

Comment: Have you checked your script is running? Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

...should be:

```
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                                     //
```

See it working:

```js
let column;

function optionSelect() {
  const el = document.getElementById("seleccion");
  column = [+el.options[el.selectedIndex].value].filter(o => o);
  console.log(column);
}

document.getElementById('seleccion').addEventListener('change', optionSelect);
optionSelect();
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id="seleccion">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for my coding, I am starting.

Comment: @MAA, relax, you're doing just fine. Even after you'll be considered an expert, you'll still be learning new stuff every single day. That's what coding is about, at core, so get used to it.